# Google Cloud Engine - Change External IP address from CA to SG

Tags: networking, ip, cloud, google-compute-engine

I have google cloud compute engine which is centOS 7. It was located in asia-southeast1 (SG). However, I checked the external IP it was on the Mountain View, CA.

Is it possible to change the IP where it can be located to Singapore?

Thanks,
Edmhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. At this moment you need to:
1 Reserve a new IP in the wanted region.
2 Stop your VM.
3 Assign the new IP to your VM.
4 Re-Start your VM

It is easier to do it through the console, but will take more time. If you decide to do it with gcloud. You need to delete the access and Assign the new one.

Delete access
gcloud compute instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]

gcloud compute instances delete-access-config [INSTANCE_NAME] \
    --access-config-name "[ACCESS_CONFIG_NAME]"

Define the new IP reserved ( here you specify the actual IP x.x.x.x, not its name)

gcloud compute instances add-access-config [INSTANCE_NAME] \
    --access-config-name "[ACCESS_CONFIG_NAME]" --address [IP_ADDRESS]

Assign the IP to the VM

gcloud compute instances add-access-config [INSTANCE_NAME] \
    --access-config-name "[ACCESS_CONFIG_NAME]"

The official documentation has also the step by step.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses