# Changing External IP's Geolocation of Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-vpn

I am creating my own VPN server. I want it to have an IP address of (say) Canada. I created an Compute Instance in the region of my choice and reserved a static IP in that region as well but when I check the external IP Geolocation it still says Mountain view CA. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430812/google-cloud-engine-change-external-ip-address-from-ca-to-sg) but it didn't worked.

In AWS when I chose a region the IP is located in that region itself.

I would like to know how to change Geolocation of External IP in Google Compute?

Comment: I don't see any option for choosing the IP localisation. But it's not because I never see it that doesn't exist.

Comment: They must have it maybe with some other service name. None the less I want to have localized IP for my Instance

Comment: Here I found an Issue like this : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112448138

Comment: I still don't know if it's possible to have external IP location set to particular region

Comment: Do you have an IP address to share?

Answer (score 3):

By Default all External IP addresses provided by GCP will always show that it is hosted in Mountain View (which is the Google headquarters). But it doesn't necessarily means that it is hosted there.  Right now, there is no way to change the IP geolocation. This Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988170/why-do-google-cloud-platform-static-ip-addresses-list-mountain-view-ca-in-rever?answertab=votes#tab-top) has more detailed explanation.

But, there is already a Feature Request with GCP support to show the proper IP location. Just remember that, Google does not provides ETA or when it will be implemented. You can consult this feature request in the [next URL](https://issuetracker.google.com/72263361) where updates will be posted, you can also use this same link to post any comment to make developers aware that more people is requesting this.

Comment: They are now implementing. No ETA though. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72263361#comment39