# After Connecting OpenVPN with Google VPC, can not able to surf internet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, openvpn

I have connected OpenVPN with Google Cloud VPC by following youtube video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avYcoMKaXRc

Right now I am in Singapore and wants to connect Google Cloud India, setup is perfect but after successful connection if I try to open any website, on-one is opening, like there is no internet connection.

Can any one help me what is the issue? thanks

Comment: Most likely you have a routing problem where Internet traffic is being sent over the VPN. However, there are no details in your question to help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To monitor and solve common issues with Cloud VPN, follow the GCP Cloud VPN [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/support/troubleshooting) and [OpenVPN troubleshooting](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/troubleshooting/).

Even the VPN gateways are configured correctly, there could be issue in the peer network between the hosts and the gateway, or with the network between the peer gateway and the Cloud VPN gateway.

- Check for the Cloud VPN logs in [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs) and verify these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/support/troubleshooting#vpn-loggin).
- Verify [connectivity](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/support/troubleshooting#checking_connectivity) between your host and Google Cloud VMs;

  - Are you able to reach peer VPN gateway from your host.
  - Verify that traffic is flowing between the two VPN gateways in both directions. In the VPN logs, check for reported incoming messages from the other VPN gateway.
- Make sure to configure your peer VPN gateway to use [MTU of no greater than 1460 bytes](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/mtu-considerations#gateway_mtu_vs_system_mtu).
- Check [network throughput](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/network-throughput), both within GCP and your host.
- Check if [supported IKE ciphers](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/support/troubleshooting#ike-cipher-overview) are configured.

Comment: Seems like multiple users who installed the script have similar issue (check YouTube comments) and tried below steps to resolve it:
-> sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
Uncomment line-> net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Also, Owner mentioned "Script Updated. Video wont show you some steps" as first comment. If you still have issue try assigning issue to skiddow - https://github.com/skiddow/OpenVPN (Owner of the script)

Comment: Thank you so much Gagandeep, still having issue with Google Cloud like, if I have selected region of India, it still shows me ip of Mountain View :( so there is no use of VPN as India.. Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754134/changing-external-ips-geolocation-of-google-compute-engine

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the **ufw firewall** that is active.
You can check the status by running the command

```
sudo ufw status
```

In the output you will see

```
Status: active
```

Now just execute

```
sudo ufw disable
```

This will disable the firewall and now try reconnecting to the server, internet will work.